# Преобразовать переменную int в const int

Tags: c++, массивы, инициализация, int

Из функции было получено значение int поля, с помощью ссылки в параметрах, теперь мне нужно создать массив с размером значения int поля. Как преобразовать int в const int

Comment: Если размер массива не известен на этапе компиляции, то используйте `std::vector` / выделяйте память динамически с помощью `new []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не поняли сакральный смысл `const int` *при объявлении массива*. Важна не константность (неизменяемость во время выполнения) этого размера, а его известность *во время компиляции*, т.е. по сути это не `const`, а `constexpr`.

Поэтому массив надо создавать динамически:

```
int n;
// Получение значения n

double * а = new double[n];

// Работа с массивом a

delete[] a;  // Освобождение выделенной памяти
```

а так, конечно, никто не мешает написать

```
const int m = n;
```

и это будет работать. Только вот использовать `m` как размер массива - не получится.

Comment: Снова здравствуйте и снова спасибо

Comment: Ну, если ответ вас устроил, то вы можете его принять — птичка слева от ответа. Это здесь спасибо имеет такой вид :)